# Width of a ListBoxFor should always stretch maximal in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "Id", "Name"))
```

The above asp.net mvc code renders a `<select>-tag.`

How can I set the width to stretch horizontally 100% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code above will render "select" tag with multiple="multiple" attribute.
Now, not sure if I understand your problem but if you set attribute style="width:100%" on select tag it will stretch horizontally.

Please correct me if I missed your point.

Comment: in the rendered html the id of the Select-control is id="selectedIds" when I do this in my css file: #SelectedIds { width:300px; } it has no effect?

Comment: Than it must be something else...just tested this
<select id="TimeZoneId" class="select" name="TimeZoneId" multiple="multiple">...</select>
and it works perfect when set in css "select {width: 100%;}"

Comment: Maybe to post full html render and css file

Comment: I decided to use new { @class = "select"} in my ListBoxFor because actually #myselectedIds does not make sense for a single listbox when the others have the same width...

Answer (score 0):

but... this worked:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "Id", "Name"),new {style="width:100%;"} )
```

Comment: Glad you got it work but external css also has to work and it is better practice than inline style.

Comment: this is true. I used the small #selectedIds css I try and debug again maybe something is wrong elsewhere... ah I just see you used the select html tag in the css, well I do not want all select tags to stretch maybe... therefore I tried the id.

Comment: You can try with class name:

<select class="myselect" >...</select> 

and in css

.myselect {width: 100%; }